# I am installing flutter for the first time and even after editing the path i am not able to use it in all my terminals

Tags: flutter, dart, installation

I am using a Mac and added the following to my .bash_profile file after successfully downloading flutter,

```
export PATH="$PATH:/Users/aaditya/development/tools/flutter/bin"
```

It is working if I use it in a particular terminal after exporting the path but not in every terminal as it should. I get the following error message if I try to use it,

```
zsh: command not found: flutter
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

looks like you are using zsh...

- open, or create,  `~/.zshrc`
- add this line: `export PATH=~/somwhere/flutter/bin:$PATH`
- close it and in your terminal: `source ~/.zshrc`

This should do the trick ;)

Answer (score 0):

Add `PATH="$PATH:/Users/aaditya/development/tools/flutter/bin"` to `~/.bashrc`, then run:

```
source ~/.bashrc // to refresh your .bashrc file
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out, i was using the zsh terminal and hence had to add it to the .zshrc file